# Transparent Qt window on top of DirectX

Tags: qt, user-interface, directx, transparency, hud

**I want to make a transparent frame-less QWidget which looks like it is being rendered on top of another QWidget.**

My intention is to create a **HUD** on top of a 3D-game using **DirectX** and **Qt**.

In my efforts so far my QMainWindow contains a custom made DirectX-Widget, which is created by handing the HWND of an ordinary QWidget to DirectX when creating the swap chain in DirectX, and then creating a custom render loop by using a QTimer (*see code below*).

I then try to render a new **Overlay**-widget (my intended HUD) on top of the QMainWindow and make it appear like it is part of the main window.

**By using the following flags on the Overlay I can make it behave similarly to what I want, but I still can't get rid off the frame.**

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
```

The **left** image shows what it really looks like, and by the magic of MS Paint the **right** image is how I would like it to be.

[image: Debug image]

As you can see from the picture the transparency does **not** work on top of the DirectX-widget, but it appears to be working on top of ordinary Widgets such as the **toolbar**, and the same appears to be true when I experimented using something like QPainter instead of DirectX.

*Does anyone know why this is happening? Any suggestions on how to get rid of the frame in DirectX or to achieve something similar?*

---

**Source code**

You can download the full **Visual Studio 2010** project from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12273871/%28Program%29/Qt%20DirectX%20transperancy%20problem.zip).

*Probably requires **Visual Studio Add-in 1.1.11 for Qt4** and **June 2010 DirectX SDK** if you want to compile it yourself.*

Most of the source code is also shown below. I tried to make it as short as possible.

```
#pragma once

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_overlay.h"

class DXWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QTimer* timer;
public:
    DXWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent){}
    ~DXWidget()
    {
        // dx cleanup
    };
    void init(HWND windowHandle)
    {
        // init DirectX using our HWND as render target
        initDX(windowHandle);

        // start render loop
        timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(render()));
        timer->start(0);
    }
private:
    void initDX(HWND windowHandle)
    {
        // inits DirectX stuff
    }
private slots:
    void render()
    {
        // renders a frame to the Widget using DirectX
    }
};

class Overlay : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Ui::Overlay ui;
public:
    Overlay(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);
        QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
        QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
        show();
        move(6, 50); // move window so we can see it overlapping our toolbar
    };
    ~Overlay()
    {
    };
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
    DXWidget* widget;
public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        // setup window
        ui.setupUi(this);

        // create DirectX-widget
        widget = new DXWidget(this);
        MainWindow::setCentralWidget(widget);

        // hand HWND to DirectXs swap chain so
        // we can draw to that window
        widget->init(widget->winId());

        // create overlay
        new Overlay(this);
    };
};
```

Comment: hi! have you come up with solution?

Comment: @jungle_mole I don't recommend it, but in the game we made I basically had the Overlay as a separate QMainWindow, readjusted the Overlay on every Move or Resize event from the MainWindow. It worked, but I can't say  if it will hold in a serious project. 

It's not the best code that I've written, but I think these are the most relevant classes if you want to have a look (use at your own discretion):
https://github.com/L0mion/xkill-source/blob/08709ac9cff31b4b1dd05a1aff3884fa4def3a90/xkill-gui/Menu_Main.cpp
https://github.com/L0mion/xkill-source/blob/master/xkill-gui/Menu_HUD.cpp